# Proving a a function is continuous using ε and δ definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

how would one go about proving the continuity of 
\begin{equation}
  f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
    \sin^2(\pi/x) & \text{ for } \frac1{n+1} \leq x\leq\frac1n\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I've tried using that  $f_n(x)$ is continuous at c if and only if for every $ε>0 $,   $∃ δ>0$ such that

$$|x-c|<\delta ⟹ |f(x)−f(c)|<\epsilon$$

so

$$|\sin^2(\pi/x) - \sin^2(\pi/c)| < \epsilon$$

For some $|x-c|<\delta$

But I did not get very far, is this the right definition to use? Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to complete this proof? Sorry if this isn't formatted well I'm new to LaTeX. Thanks

Comment: What does $n$ do here ?

Comment: Your $\TeX$ was fine. I've made a few touches here and there (double dollar signs, adding `\ ` in front of `sin` and using fractions in the `cases`) , but none of them were strictly necessary.

Comment: As n increases, the interval 1/(n+1) to 1/n will change. Between these values the function is not 0 

All other values including the boundary the function equals 0

Comment: Do you have to worry much about the cases where $c<1/(n+1)$ or in between or $>1/n$? The continuity of just 0 or just that $sin^2$ vs the continuity that requires both.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin (x)$ is continuous all you have to do is check continuity at the points $x=\frac 1 n $ and $x=\frac 1 {n+1} $ For this use continuity of $\sin (x)$ and  the fact that $\sin (n\pi)=\sin ((n+1)\pi)=0$.

Comment: Defining a sequence of functions, but just proving continuity for particular n

Comment: Ok thanks. So should I just take the limit as of f(x) as x approaches 1/n and also take the limit as x approaches 1/(n+1) and show that these limits are equal to 0?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to do to prove continuity.